# How Can I Remove A Single Parent From Firebase?

Tags: jquery, html, database, firebase, removechild

In Firebase, there is a tree that holds data using parents, elements, and childs. Like so:

`m3r945ba1lh
-JTHUY9SMruiPaKW6-SW
 calendar: "2014-08-14"
 name: "apple"
 -JTHWE66v3E7NTuUidfM
 calendar: ""
 name: "hello"
 text: "10101"
 -JTHWFAYBxIZjOixh8ZZ
 calendar: ""
 name: "sos"
 text: "111"`

I need to delete the data that is slanted, but one bolded data set at a time.

I have tried using `myDataRef.remove();`
but it deletes ALL data stored.

I have also tried `$(this).parent().remove();`
but it doesn't work at all

anybody know how to delete one at a time?

Comment: Do you want to remove the parents too, or just the data inside them?

Comment: the parents too please

Comment: $(this) looks like jQuery. Not sure what that could be intending to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query the root and remove the children by iterating through them.

```
var rootRef = new FireBase('https://your-url.firebase.com/');
    rootRef.once('value', function(snapshot){
       var children = snapshot.val();
       for(var child_id in children) {
            // Create a reference to it
            var child = rootRef.child(child_id);
            child.remove();
       }
    });
```

Comment: Rather than for(key in val) you should utilize snapshot.forEach(function(ss){ ss.ref().remove() });

Comment: thanks!  but i found something that works better, sorry

Comment: @yvonnegone , mind share it? I'm looking for a solution to remove a specific parent as well